# Определить устройства, подключенные к одному роутеру

Tags: wifi

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я каким-либо образом определить уникальный идентификатор роутера, к которому в данный момент подключен? Любыми средствами.

Спасибо!

Comment: cmd/terminal > arp -a

Comment: @Costa примерно та же, что кто-то в сетке решил пошаманить с устройствами и подменить им мак-адреса. Насколько понимаю, для сетки вообще не может существовать второго устройства с идентичным мак-адресом.